# Using WebClient.DownloadString()

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have a strange problem when usinng WebClient.DownloadString(). It is very very slow and sometimes does not work but if I try browsing using IE9/Chrome to the website everything works fine.

Here is the code:

```
        var req = new WebClient();
        req.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string result = string.Empty;
        result = req.DownloadString(someURL);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code. Without seeing what you are trying to do it's going to be virtually impossible to help you.

Comment: post some more details e/o code. How big is the returned string ? Did you consider using downloadstringasync ?

Comment: show us code... how do you except us to guess what's wrong ?

Comment: does your system use a proxy server ?

Comment: @SteveB There is not sroxy server

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you sent is correct ( a part the `string result = string.Empty;` that is absolutely pointless). If you feel the application blocking you should consider using [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync.aspx).

Comment: That is not the problem, for some reason it takes forever while using the IE9 to browse to the same website is fairly quick. I am also using UTF8 encoding if it means anything

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting `WebClient.Proxy` to [`GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.globalproxyselection.getemptywebproxy.aspx)